# Can't scroll webview in Android

Tags: android, webview

I got some strange problem with my WebView. The problem is that I can't scroll the page in Android 2.2 and 2.3 if it's longer than the screen. The only way to scroll the WebView is in Android 4.0.3. What's the problem or is it just not possible to scroll the WebView in Android versions lower than 4.0.3?

This is my layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:id="@+id/rltvLayout01"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:background="@color/white">  
    <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/LinearLayout01"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_above="@+id/ad_layout">
            <WebView android:id="@+id/webview"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                android:scrollbars="none" />
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/ad_layout"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">
            <com.google.ads.AdView android:id="@+id/ad"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                ads:adUnitId="-------------"
                ads:loadAdOnCreate="true"
                ads:adSize="BANNER" />
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

**EDIT 23:06:**

I just found the problem! The actual code I'm using is not causing this behavior, it's the loaded website that's causing the problem. In my mobile website i'm using viewport to show it correctly and FroYo and Gingerbread's WebView can't handle that well. So after removing the viewport meta tag it works perfect! Thank you anyway Thomas K, the vertical orientation also made it scrollable after removing the viewport!

**So get rid of the viewport tag in your html code if you want to have your webview working in Froyo and Gingerbread!**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add

```
android:orientation="vertical"
```

or

```
android:orientation="horizontal"
```

to LinearLayout

Comment: For some reason I still can't scroll :(

Comment: Is it possible that it has something to do with the relativelayout or something else? Or even maybe some other code in project? As far as I know I'm touching the vertical scrolling nowhere...

Comment: you could try to make the layout more simple. (only one linearLayout and webview). Did u try to make your webview "fill_parent" in its height?

Comment: Yes I tried that too. I also tried to make the layout only one linear and only webview. But even then I couldn't scroll. This is getting really strange :(

Comment: I posted my other source too so maybe the problem is somewhere else!