# How to make a Scroll Listener for WebView in Android

Tags: android, webview, custom-controls, scrollview

How to implement the Scroll Listener for `WebView` in Android

i tried this but its not calling my `Log.i` on scrolling the webview.

```
package com.example.webview.full.width;
import android.content.Context;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.util.Log;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.widget.AbsListView;
import android.widget.AbsListView.OnScrollListener;

public class scorllableWebview extends WebView implements OnScrollListener {


Context ctx;
AttributeSet atrs;

public scorllableWebview(Context context) {
    super(context);

    ctx = context;
}

public scorllableWebview(Context context, AttributeSet atters){
    super(context, atters);

    ctx = context;
    atrs = atters;
}

@Override
public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem,
        int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {

    Log.i("onScroll", "Called");
}

@Override
public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState) {


    Log.i("onScrollStateChanged", "Called");

}
}
```

Here is my `MainActivity.java`

```
package com.example.webview.full.width;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

ProgressDialog progressDialog;
scorllableWebview wv;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    wv = (scorllableWebview) findViewById(R.id.scorllableWebview);

    wv.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

    wv.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
    wv.getSettings().supportZoom();

    progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(MainActivity.this,
            "Loading Book...!", "Please Wait");
    progressDialog.setCancelable(true);

    String htnlString = "<!DOCTYPE html><html><body style = \"text-align:center\"><script type=\"text/javascript\">for(a=1;a<=10;a++)document.write('<img style=\"border-style:dotted;border-width:10px;border-color:black;\"src=\"http://myURL.com/books_snaps/EN567/'+a+'.jpg\" alt=\"Page Not Found\"/>');</script></body></html>";
    // width=\"100%\"
    wv.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {

        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            progressDialog.dismiss();
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Completed",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            wv.pageUp(true);
            super.onPageFinished(view, url);
        }

    });

    wv.loadDataWithBaseURL(null, htnlString, "text/html", "UTF-8", null);

}
   }
```

and here is my XML file.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<com.example.webview.full.width.scorllableWebview
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/scorllableWebview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6253444/android-webview-scrollable and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10552702/cant-scroll-webview-in-android

Comment: then what do you want?

Comment: its not calling my onScroll method while scrolling the webview. please have a look on my scorllableWebview.java class

Answer (score 92, accepted):

Something like:

```
public class ObservableWebView extends WebView
{
    private OnScrollChangedCallback mOnScrollChangedCallback;

    public ObservableWebView(final Context context)
    {
        super(context);
    }

    public ObservableWebView(final Context context, final AttributeSet attrs)
    {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public ObservableWebView(final Context context, final AttributeSet attrs, final int defStyle)
    {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onScrollChanged(final int l, final int t, final int oldl, final int oldt)
    {
        super.onScrollChanged(l, t, oldl, oldt);
        if(mOnScrollChangedCallback != null) mOnScrollChangedCallback.onScroll(l, t, oldl, oldt);
    }

    public OnScrollChangedCallback getOnScrollChangedCallback()
    {
        return mOnScrollChangedCallback;
    }

    public void setOnScrollChangedCallback(final OnScrollChangedCallback onScrollChangedCallback)
    {
        mOnScrollChangedCallback = onScrollChangedCallback;
    }

    /**
     * Impliment in the activity/fragment/view that you want to listen to the webview
     */
    public static interface OnScrollChangedCallback
    {
        public void onScroll(int l, int t, int oldl, int oldt);
    }
}
```

Should work, this is untested but this works for almost every other view in Android.

You would implement like:

```
wv = (ObservableWebView) findViewById(R.id.scorllableWebview);
wv.setOnScrollChangedCallback(new OnScrollChangedCallback(){
    public void onScroll(int l, int t, int oldl, int oldt){
        if(t> oldt){
            //Do stuff
            System.out.println("Swipe UP");
            //Do stuff
        }
        else if(t< oldt){
            System.out.println("Swipe Down");
        }
        Log.d(TAG,"We Scrolled etc...");
    }
});
```

Comment: @Chris.Jenkins it didn't worked, it gave an error on line where we used findViewBid of ClassCastException

Comment: @AnasReza You have to make sure you implement your `ObservableWebView` in your XML file. This was implied.

Comment: @Chris.Jenkins yeah thanks i implemented in my XML file and it worked fine

Comment: nt tek = (int) Math.floor(mTermsCondWV.getContentHeight() * mTermsCondWV.getScale());
           
                if(tek - mTermsCondWV.getScrollY() == mTermsCondWV.getHeight()){
                    mAgreeBT.setEnabled(true);
                    mAgreeBT.setBackground(ContextCompat.getDrawable(getActivity(),R.drawable.button_bg));
                }

Comment: I use this code for end of the scroll but its not working in naugat

Comment: @AmitVerma literally see the answer below: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34110402/803225

Comment: UI flicker on scrolling.

Comment: Hi its not working for the latest version apis , can you please update answer

Comment: is there any way to do for IOS ?

Comment: @MukeshLokare Could I ask which version api is not working for you?

Answer (score 23):

Since API 23, you won't need to do it anymore, you can just use the new [OnScrollChangeListener](http://developer.android.com/intl/pt-br/reference/android/view/View.OnScrollChangeListener.html)  available on all views, including on the **WebView**. But as you still need to support older versions, you can still use the suggestion from @Chris.Jenkins. I made some adjustments the proposed class to be 'more compatible' with the new OnScrollChangeListener interface:

```
public class ObservableWebView extends WebView {
private OnScrollChangeListener onScrollChangeListener;

public ObservableWebView(Context context) {
    super(context);
}

public ObservableWebView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
}

public ObservableWebView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
}

@Override
protected void onScrollChanged(int l, int t, int oldl, int oldt) {
    super.onScrollChanged(l, t, oldl, oldt);
    if (onScrollChangeListener != null) {
        onScrollChangeListener.onScrollChange(this, l, t, oldl, oldt);
    }
}

public void setOnScrollChangeListener(OnScrollChangeListener onScrollChangeListener) {
    this.onScrollChangeListener = onScrollChangeListener;
}

public OnScrollChangeListener getOnScrollChangeListener() {
    return onScrollChangeListener;
}

public interface OnScrollChangeListener {
    /**
     * Called when the scroll position of a view changes.
     *
     * @param v          The view whose scroll position has changed.
     * @param scrollX    Current horizontal scroll origin.
     * @param scrollY    Current vertical scroll origin.
     * @param oldScrollX Previous horizontal scroll origin.
     * @param oldScrollY Previous vertical scroll origin.
     */
    void onScrollChange(WebView v, int scrollX, int scrollY, int oldScrollX, int oldScrollY);
}
}
```

Comment: @LucasS.Müller : you have to support backward version so you can't simply ignore it

Comment: Hi Alecio its not working for the latest version apis

Answer (score 10):

There is no need to extend WebView.
What about:

```
webView.getViewTreeObserver().addOnScrollChangedListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnScrollChangedListener() {
    @Override
    public void onScrollChanged() {
        Log.v(TAG, "+++ scrollchanged "+webView.getScrollY());
    }
});
```

Comment: And what is the webView Scroll Stop Listener ?

Comment: workin in 2022 best answer... for webview...

Comment: Still 100% workable in 2023.

Answer (score 6):

Here is more elegant Kotlin version of accepted answer

```
class ObservableWebView @JvmOverloads constructor(
        context: Context,
        attrs: AttributeSet? = null,
        defStyleAttr: Int = 0
) : WebView(context, attrs, defStyleAttr) {
    var scrollListener: WebViewScrollListener? = null

    override fun onScrollChanged(scrollX: Int, scrollY: Int, oldScrollX: Int, oldScrollY: Int) {
        super.onScrollChanged(scrollX, scrollY, oldScrollX, oldScrollY)
        when {
            scrollY > oldScrollY -> scrollListener?.onScrollDown()
            scrollY < oldScrollY -> scrollListener?.onScrollUp()
        }
        scrollListener?.onScroll(scrollX, scrollY, oldScrollX, oldScrollY)
    }
}

interface WebViewScrollListener{
    fun onScroll(scrollX: Int, scrollY: Int, oldScrollX: Int, oldScrollY: Int)

    fun onScrollDown()

    fun onScrollUp()
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can try this:

It works for API >= 23 Android Marshmallow

```
web.setOnScrollChangeListener(new View.OnScrollChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onScrollChange(View p1, int p2, int p3, int p4, int p5)
            {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext, "Scrolled", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 2):

From `API 23` (`Android - 6.0`) , You can implement `WebView.OnScrollChangeListener` like

```
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements WebView.OnScrollChangeListener
    {
         @Override
         public void onScrollChange(View v, int scrollX, int scrollY, int oldScrollX, int oldScrollY) 
         {
             if(oldScrollY < scrollY) 
             {
                 //Scrolling Upwards
             }
             else if(oldScrollY > scrollY)
             {
                 //Scrolling Downwards
             }
         }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this (for all view what you want):
Сreate a GestureDetector then a TouchListener and set to a view who scrolling

```
OnCreate
         private GestureDetector gestureDetector;
         gestureDetector = new GestureDetector(this, new 
         GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX, float 
           velocityY) {

                    if (velocityY < 0) {
                        collapse(frToolBar);

                    } else if (velocityY > 0) {
                        if (frToolBar.getVisibility()==View.GONE)
                        expand(frToolBar);
                    }
                    return super.onFling(e1, e2, velocityX, velocityY);
                }

                @Override
                public boolean onDown(MotionEvent e) {
                    return super.onDown(e);
                }
            });

          webView.setOnTouchListener((view, motionEvent) -> 
          gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(motionEvent));


    Two method - 

           public static void expand(final View v) {
            v.measure(WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,  
          indowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
             // final int targetHeight = v.getMeasuredHeight();
            final int targetHeight = v.getHeight();
            v.getLayoutParams().height = 1;
            v.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            Animation a = new Animation() {
                @Override
                protected void applyTransformation(float interpolatedTime, Transformation t) 
           {
                    v.getLayoutParams().height = interpolatedTime == 1
                            ? WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
                            : (int) (targetHeight * interpolatedTime);
                    v.requestLayout();
                }

                @Override
                public boolean willChangeBounds() {
                    return true;
                }
            };
            a.setDuration(300);
            v.startAnimation(a);

        }


        public static void collapse(final View v) {
            final int initialHeight = v.getMeasuredHeight();
            Animation a = new Animation() {
                @Override
                protected void applyTransformation(float interpolatedTime, Transformation t) 
           {
                    if (interpolatedTime == 1) {
                        v.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    } else {
                        v.getLayoutParams().height = initialHeight - (int) (initialHeight * 
              interpolatedTime);
                        v.requestLayout();
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public boolean willChangeBounds() {
                    return true;
                }
            };
            a.setDuration(300);
            v.startAnimation(a);

        }
```

Comment: please explain your answer

Comment: Сreate a gesturdektor then touchlister and set to a view who scrolling