# How to hide footer while scrolling up webview in android?

Tags: android, scroll, webview, footer

I have webview with linear layout with three buttons at bottom i.e. footer. I want to hide that footer while scrolling up webview and show footer on scrolling down.

Please Help me!!!

Comment: set scrollview listener and hide the footer.

Comment: @Surender can you please elaborate..

Answer (score 0):

Try this,  I also never tried so let me know if it worked or not.

```
 scroll.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

                if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {

                   //show footer
                }
else  if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {

                   //hide footer
                }    
                return false;
            }
    });
```

Comment: Check here  - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8181828/android-detect-when-scrollview-stops-scrolling  ,  may you get some help.

Comment: I think that example is for scrollview. I want for webview

Comment: oops sorry..!! check this one this is for webview - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14752523/how-to-make-a-scroll-listener-for-webview-in-android

Comment: Sorry bro, then i don't know