# OnScrollChange does not fire for Webview

Tags: android, xamarin

I think I am doing something wrong here,

I added `WebView.IOnScrollChangeListener` in my activity

```
MainActivity : Activity, WebView.IOnScrollChangeListener
```

Then created an `interface` in the same activity

```
void WebView.IOnScrollChangeListener.OnScrollChange(View v, int scrollX, int scrollY, int oldScrollX, int oldScrollY)
  {
    Log.Info("101028", "scrolled??");
  }
```

Then I set the `OnScrollChangeListener` on my `WebView`

```
webView.SetOnScrollChangeListener(this);
```

The issue is, `void WebView.IOnScrollChangeListener.OnScrollChange` never fires

I also tried the following, but this also does not work

```
webView.ScrollChange += (o, e) => { Log.Info("101028", "scrolled??"); };
```

any idea what am I doing wrong here?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14752523/how-to-make-a-scroll-listener-for-webview-in-android

Comment: Hi, I saw that but the initial step is to extend the activity with WebView and when I do that in Xamarin I get the error  `public class MainActivity : Activity, WebView` -- `can not have multiple base classes` which does make sense

Comment: Oh Wait... I think i am reading it wrong

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> public class MainActivity : Activity, WebView -- can not have multiple base classes

There should be only one base class `Activity`, you can't inherit two class, the `WebView` should be an interface: `View.IOnScrollChangeListener`, and then implement the method:

```
public void OnScrollChange(View v, int scrollX, int scrollY, int oldScrollX, int oldScrollY)
{
    Log.Info("101028", "scrolled??");
}
```