# How to detect vertical scroll in webview android?

Tags: android, webview

I need to detect when vertical scroll happens in webview android. How to do that? I had used ObservableWebView, but it detects zoom in and zoom out.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make a Scroll Listener for WebView in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14752523/how-to-make-a-scroll-listener-for-webview-in-android)

Comment: AFAIK There is no such class as `ObservableWebView` provided by `Android SDk`

Comment: The best way I found scroll is using OnTouchListener. The code is as follows  webView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
@Override
public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
float initialY = (float)motionEvent.getY();
switch (motionEvent.getAction()) {
case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
float finalY = (float)motionEvent.getX();
if (initialY < finalY) {
Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Scrolled up", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}else if (initialY > finalY) {
Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Scrolled down", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}break;
}return false;
}});