# How to open a web browser in WebView app when an external link is clicked?

Tags: android, android-intent, webview, android-webview, back-button

I want to open external links in web browser using intent and should not open in my WebView app except my internal links starts with "https://www.ecommerce.in/"
I have written code as given below:

```
@Override
 public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) 
 {
  if (!url.contains("https://www.ecommerce.in/")) 
  {
   Uri uri = Uri.parse(url);
   startActivity(Intent.createChooser(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri), "Choose browser"));
   view.loadUrl(url);
   CookieManager.getInstance().setAcceptCookie(true);
  } else {
          webViewProduct.loadUrl(url);
          return true;
         }
 }
```

This code is working perfectly as I want but the problem is when I pressed back button on web browser the same external link is opening in my WebView app.

Please let me know where I'm doing wrong. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should have to remove `view.loadUrl(url)` from you code , So

Please replace your code as given below

```
@Override
 public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) 
 {
  if (!url.contains("https://www.ecommerce.in/")) 
  {
   Uri uri = Uri.parse(url);
   startActivity(Intent.createChooser(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri), "Choose browser"));

   CookieManager.getInstance().setAcceptCookie(true);
  } else {
          webViewProduct.loadUrl(url);
          return true;
         }
 }
```

Comment: Thankyou. Its working fine. Could yo please help me about Fading Toolbar in WebView while scrolling up Toolbar Should fade to show and scrolling down Toolbar should fade to hide. I searched for this in Stack Overflow and in Google. But couldn't find any correct solution for this. Hope, I get a solution for this. Once again thank you for your help.

Comment: ok you can prefer this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14752523/how-to-make-a-scroll-listener-for-webview-in-android

Comment: Hi, Than you for your support. I have tried the given link but it showing error message at _Log.d(TAG,"We Scrolled etc...");_                        wv = (ObservableWebView) findViewById(R.id.scorllableWebview);
wv.setOnScrollChangedCallback(new OnScrollChangedCallback(){
    public void onScroll(int l, int t, int oldl, int oldt){
        if(t> oldt){
            //Do stuff
            System.out.println("Swipe UP");
            //Do stuff
        }
        else if(t< oldt){
            System.out.println("Swipe Down");
        }
        Log.d(TAG,"We Scrolled etc...");
    }
});