# How to hide and show a RelativeLayout header when scrolling a webview?

Tags: android

Currently, I have a `webView` with custom `relativeLayout` header, and when I scroll up, the `webView` the header should be hidden.
And when I scroll down the header should be visible.

Please suggest me any idea about.

Comment: Please provide a code snippet of your current implementation.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to implement scroll listener for that. [see this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14753235/9792247)

After implementing scroll listener for webview, you will get two conditions (up scroll & down scroll).

so, hide your relative layout header on scroll down and show it on scroll up.

```html
wv.setOnScrollChangedCallback(new OnScrollChangedCallback(){
    public void onScroll(int l, int t, int oldl, int oldt){
        if(t> oldt){
            header.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
        else if(t< oldt){
            header.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    }
});
```

You can also make an animation transition for the same for the better user experience.

Answer (score -1):

```html
wv.setOnScrollChangedCallback(new OnScrollChangedCallback(){
    public void onScroll(int l, int t, int oldl, int oldt){
        if(t> oldt){
            header.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
        else if(t< oldt){
            header.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    }
});
```

when i implement this code then at the time of scrolling both condition are executing.that's why its showing visible and gone at the same time.

Comment: No, it's not possible that both conditions will true at the same time, as the second condition is in else part.