# How to hide bottom navigation from fragment on webview scroll

Tags: android, android-webview, bottomnavigationview

Hello i have a problem with hide `BottomNavigationView` from fragment on `WebView` scroll below my code

**Main Activity**

```
@SuppressLint("Assert")
public void hideBottomNavigationView(boolean b) {
    if (b)
    {
        BottomNavigationView Bview = null;
        assert false;
        Bview.clearAnimation();
        Bview.animate().translationY(Bview.getHeight()).setDuration(300);
    }
    else
    {
        BottomNavigationView Bview = null;
        assert false;
        Bview.clearAnimation();
        Bview.animate().translationY(0).setDuration(300);
    }
}
```

**Fragment**

```
webView.setOnScrollChangeListener(new View.OnScrollChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onScrollChange(View v, int scrollX, int scrollY, int oldScrollX, int oldScrollY) {
            if (scrollY>200)
            {
                ((MainActivity)getActivity()).hideBottomNavigationView(true);
            }
            else
            {
                ((MainActivity)getActivity()).hideBottomNavigationView(false);
            }
        }
    });
```

I don't know where i am doing wrong please help me to hiding `BottomNavigation` from fragment.

Comment: Print log in fragments in both `if` and `else` section see what you get.

Comment: sir i am not testing my app on emulator because my laptop not supporting emulator

Comment: just wanted to know that is `onScrollChange` is getting called or not

Comment: yes sir onScrollChange work when webview scrollY > 200 then app automatically close

Comment: then share error and exceptions.

Comment: i don't know sir where can i get that error because my emulator not working

Comment: possible duplicate, check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14752523/how-to-make-a-scroll-listener-for-webview-in-android) out

Comment: no sir there is now any solution for it

Comment: You can see errors and exceptions in Logcat window of Android Studio. Without exception we cannot help you. sorry.

Comment: @AshishKudale sir can you tell me how can i hide bottom navigation bar from fragment?

Comment: you should be us CoordinatorLayout .

Comment: refere this link :https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44777869/hide-show-bottomnavigationview-on-scroll